How can i make this idea work in PCB?
Assume i have a source of energy (voltage source), i want to sense the voltage and current of this source and transfer this analog information to an ADC (arduino nano)
thus i have to make the voltage/current sensed into a valid range thats acceptable by the ADC components this is what i tried to do:

So in this image you see a voltage pin on the bottom left where the source exist, and i made a voltage divider to make the voltage source actual voltage dropped by a factor to make it acceptable by the ADC, from there i take it to the current sensor "ACS712ELCTR-30A-T" i take its Vout to the ADC and i continue the loop back to the pin 2 of the voltage source. my question is : is this setup valid? does it need improvement?
EDIT
Does this new update makes it better ?


you can't measure both voltage and current with only two terminals.  there's not enough information above to suggest what should change.   I guess it's possible that having the 10K and the 180K in parallel is the right thing, but that seems unlikely.

show the circuit connected to "21"  lower left corner including any other inter connections from that circuit to this circuit.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні thats the problem, i dont know how the source that constitute the DC-bus line are connected to the sensors, i think this might need another post?

Probably you need to connect the bottom end of R2 to GND, but that's a guess.

The voltage divider should be in parallel with your voltage source, i.e. "across" it. The current sensor should be in series with the source and load.

Thank you, before i click accept your answer can you quickly check the edit i dont want to make it long in the comments, thank you again.

Is pin 2 of the connector going to the load or to ground?

thank you, i honestly dont know to what the pin 2 is conncted to .

it's kind of hard to design a circuit to deal with an unknown corcumstance.
